# Getting result between two strings without including them in the result?

Tags: c++, regex

How can we get only the result between `source="` and `"` (in this case: `192.168.10.10:any`)
using rexEx?

`<rule source="192.168.10.10:any" destination="any:any" protocol="UDP"/>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it write on c++, but the regex is:

```
<rule source="([^"]*)"
```

Comment: but the result should be only the string that between he 2 given strings, not including the two strings themselvs

Comment: @user2216190 What do you mean by 2 given strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
source="([^"]*)"
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kH2yZ6)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In `C++`, you can use

```
string s = "<rule source=\"192.168.10.10:any\" destination=\"any:any\" protocol=\"UDP\"/>";

const regex r(".*\"(.*)\" destination.*");  
smatch sm;

string result;
if (regex_search(s, sm, r))
    result =  sm[1];
```

This will give you:

```
result = "192.168.10.10:any"
```

Full code and live demo is available here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c654bb7cf4f34b93